# Postgres RETURNING with WHERE

Tags: sql, postgresql

This query returns all items, not just the ones that match `filtered = 'B'`. I have to put `filtered = 'B'` in the outer `WHERE` for it to work. Why does it work this way?

```
UPDATE mytable SET status = 'A'
FROM
(
  SELECT id FROM mytable
  WHERE filtered = 'B' and (status = 'C' or status = 'D')
  ORDER BY status NULLS LAST
  LIMIT 100
  FOR UPDATE
) sub
WHERE mytable.id = sub.id
RETURNING mytable.id
```

How can I get it to filter appropriately in the inner query? I could put the filter in the outer query but then it isn't clear what goes in the inner and the outer query and is more difficult to understand.

The primary key of `mytable` is `(id, filtered)`.

Comment: Your query seems to work as expected for me, no need outer `WHERE`

Comment: @OtoShavadze I didn't mention that the primary key of the table is compound of `id` and `filtered`. Would that have something to do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the *whole* primary key to join the tables:

```
UPDATE mytable SET status = 'A'
FROM
(
  SELECT id, filtered FROM mytable
  WHERE filtered = 'B' and (status = 'C' or status = 'D')
  ORDER BY status NULLS LAST
  LIMIT 100
  FOR UPDATE
) sub
WHERE (mytable.id, mytable.filtered) = (sub.id, sub.filtered)
RETURNING mytable.id;
```

Comment: Could you say in which cases you can use that shorter syntax for the last `WHERE` with multiple items in the parenthesis? Is it only used for joins or in any cases where you're comparing multiple columns/values for equality?

Comment: The columns on which you join must identify a row, so be a primary or unique constraint. Otherwise other rows can "creep in".